# garbage value is obtained

Tags: c++

this is a sample of my code. i am getting the value for maximum height. but my minimum height is a garbage value. what am i doing wrong

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 20

struct DATA
{
   int id;
   string name;
   float height;
}numarray[MAX];

int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    numarray[num].height = fstr3;// contains float values from a file

    float minimum, maximum;
    minimum = numarray[0].height;
    maximum = numarray[0].height;
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        {
            if(numarray[i].height < minimum)
            {
                minimum = numarray[i].height;
            }
            else if(numarray[i].height > maximum)
            {
                maximum = numarray[i].height;
            }
        }
        cout<< minimum<< "    " << maximum<< endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure your pasted code is what you actually have. it looks really strange.

Comment: The loop looks OK to me, but the example doesn't seem complete. Where does `fstr3` come from? Are you aware that it only sets the height of the first element in the list. If you repost a complete example, you will surely get help.

Comment: @Lindy, maybe he forgot something. See the extra `{}` inside the `for` loop. Still, these do not really affect anything.

Comment: @Muggen: actually there was a multi-editing problem also. There's an extra `}` at the end (in the original code `main` scope is not closed), anyway your point is correct, something is missing in this code...

Answer (score 1):

Garbage in, garbage out.  It looks like your input routine (which you didn't post) may be populating the data incorrectly.  I'd look at the input data in the debugger (even if your choice of debugger is `printf()`).

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes that minimum is unequal to the maximum.
Solution second if should be on its own and not in else clause from first.

Comment: That might mess up the max calculation, but not the min, as I read the code.

Comment: I just overread the init line so deleted reference to missing init in my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you do initialize the array in your real code, with these modifications:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 20

struct DATA
{
   int id;
   string name;
   float height;
}numarray[MAX];

int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    numarray[num].height = fstr3;// contains float values from a file

    float minimum, maximum;
    minimum = numarray[0].height;
    maximum = numarray[0].height;
    for(int i = 1 /* skip 0 - already read */; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        if(numarray[i].height < minimum)
        {
            minimum = numarray[i].height;
        }
        // remove the else here
        if(numarray[i].height > maximum)
        {
            maximum = numarray[i].height;
        }
    }
    // move outside the loop
    cout<< minimum<< "    " << maximum<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

this should be OK